# Convert pdf file to blob c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a created a file in my service (E:\User\example.pdf) and I want to convert that to blob in my controller to download the file using axios in my front-end.

How to do that? Thanks

Comment: Do you know what a "BLOB" actually is?

Comment: Yes, I was able to do implement it using java. However, Im having a hard time figuring out how to do it in c#

Comment: Ok. What is your exact definition of "blob"? Is that supposed to be a Type of some kind? If so, from what package is it?

Comment: COnvert to a blob file

Comment: Any file is a blob. "Binary Large OBject". You need to be more specific than that.

Comment: My current implementation is that my backend will return the path of my file and I want to be able to download the file using the path. Do you have any idea how to implement that?

Comment: What path? The local path like in the Question? ("E:\User\Example.pdf")

Comment: That is my generated pdf file sir. And I want to download it using react js

Comment: I understand that. It just is not of any use to share a path of "E:\SomePathToFile\File.pdf" because it is **local** to your server machine.

Comment: My bad sir. Can you help me implement it sir?

Answer (score 0):

As previous stated, won't hurt to check more on BLOB : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction

Here is how to UPLOAD FILE TO BLOB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#upload-blobs-to-a-container